# using rperp or perp to find perpendicular of a vector

Tags: mathematics, vector, cocos2d-x

i have code local coordinate

```
Vec2 velo = Vec2(100,0);
Vec2 Heading = velo.getNormalized();
Vec2 side = Heading.perp();
Vec2 trans = Vec2(12,12);
```

then i can generate toWorldCoordinate for trans vector:

```
word.x = heading.x* trans.x + heading.y * trans.y + pos.x;
word.y = side.x* trans.x + side.y * trans.y + pos.y;
```

im trying to apply example from book: game ai by example, using cocos2dx.
in cocos2dx we have rperp and perp for aplying perpendicular.
and in my POV,  cocos y is pointing up then we should use (-y,x) that is perp function.

but its seem the actor movement y is reversed then.
im realy confused with concept right hand / left hand. **using rperp is fix the issue**. but im still not understand why rperp should be used? afaik to make y pointing up we should use perp (-y,x) which is (1,0).perp = (0,1);// the destination is upward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear as to why you are using a perpendicular. There isn't enough detail to describe the problem you are working. However, perhaps this will help.

A 2D vector can be described using the values (x, y). The left hand perpendicular and the right hand perpendicular are easily calculated.

The left hand perpendicular of (x, y) is (-y, x).
The Right hand perpendicular of (x, y) is (y, -x).

This can be easily seen with an example. On a grid where positive y is up, and positive x is to the right, a normalized vector pointing up can be written as (0, 1).

The left hand perpendicular of (0, 1) is (-1, 0).
The Right hand perpendicular of (0, 1) is (1, -0), or (1, 0).

Comment: hi, your statement :
The left hand perpendicular of (x, y) is (-y, x). The Right hand perpendicular of (x, y) is (y, -x).

pointed the issue,
on cocos2dx perp function generate (-y,x). afaik cocos2dx world is based right hand ( upward give more positive Y). but the code for perp funct in cocos2dx is based on left hand. this is what confuse me.

this is issue solved , i should use rperp version of cocos2dx instead. but in theory i should use perp.

btw this used for generate local coordinate of object.so i can transform other object to this object coordinate system. thank you anyway :).